# TextView cutting off lines because of parent's LinearLayout wrap_content in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

What I want to do is make a centered box containing some text blurbs and a button to proceed. I was able to get the box centered and not taking up the entire screen by using wrap_content, but the blurbs are several lines long, and the textviews containing them are not showing all the text. Here is what I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/content"
        android:padding="10dp"
     >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

       <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/teacher_head" 
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/home_blurb"
        android:text="@string/teacher_blurb" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/student_head"
            android:textColor="@color/black"  />

        <TextView
        android:text="@string/student_blurb" 
            style="@style/home_blurb" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/go_to_app" />


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

where home_blurb is

```
<style name="home_blurb" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>     
</style>
```

The inner LinearLayout sets itself to the width of the button, which I'm okay with, but is there any way to make it wide enough to contain all the text without setting particular pixel measurements (like screen percentage in html/css)?

Comment: you want make button wide or linearlayout? and btw wtat will be the text? how big it will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use in your second `LinearLayout`

```
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
```

so that your layout will remain in center with some space around it every time no matter how much big your text is.

if you want you can give scroll bars to each element you can do it by adding with specific max height  for each element then you can do this

`android:scrollbars="vertical"` and in code `textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

Comment: Adding 4 line of code for margin with same value is not good practice. its better if u add just `android:layout_margin="20dp"`. this will serve the same purpose as above 4 lines of code, but with single line.

Comment: yes you are right. i wrote four lines considering he is going to set different values for margin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Happens that I was using:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Don't use that. Use:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

instead. Maybe you should use android:gravity="center" on the TextView that is being cut off.

Some help:

android:layout_gravity is the Outside gravity of the View. That means, to specify the direction in which the View should touch it's parent's border.

android:gravity is the Inside gravity of that View. This means, in which direction it's contents should align.